# What Is Preventing My Conversion From String to Int When Decoding Using Swift 4’s Codable?

Tags: swift, codable

I am getting the following JSON back from a network request:

```swift
{
    "uvIndex": 5
}
```

I use the following type to decode the string-to-data result:

```swift
internal final class DataDecoder<T: Decodable> {

    internal final class func decode(_ data: Data) -> T? {
        return try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
    }

}
```

The following is the model that the data is to be transformed into:

```swift
internal struct CurrentWeatherReport: Codable {

    // MARK: Properties

    internal var uvIndex: Int?

    // MARK: CodingKeys

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case uvIndex
    }

    // MARK: Initializers

    internal init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        if let uvIndexInteger = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .uvIndex) {
            uvIndex = uvIndexInteger
        } else if let uvIndexString = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .uvIndex) {
            uvIndex = Int(uvIndexString)
        }
    }

}
```

The following are the tests used to verify the decoding:

```swift
internal final class CurrentWeatherReportTests: XCTestCase {

    internal final func test_CurrentWeather_ReturnsExpected_UVIndex_FromIntegerValue() {
        let string =
        """
        {
            "uvIndex": 5
        }
        """
        let data = DataUtility.data(from: string)
        let currentWeatherReport = DataDecoder<CurrentWeatherReport>.decode(data)
        XCTAssertEqual(currentWeatherReport?.uvIndex, 5)
    }

    internal final func test_CurrentWeather_ReturnsExpected_UVIndex_FromStringValue() {
        let string =
        """
        {
            "uvIndex": "5"
        }
        """
        let data = DataUtility.data(from: string)
        let currentWeatherReport = DataDecoder<CurrentWeatherReport>.decode(data)
        XCTAssertEqual(currentWeatherReport?.uvIndex, 5)
    }

}
```

The difference between the tests is the value of `uvIndex` in the JSON; one is a string and the other is an integer. I am expecting an integer, but I want to handle any cases in which the value may come back as a string rather than a number since that seems to be a common practice with a few APIs that I work with. However, my second test keeps failing with the following message: `XCTAssertEqual failed: ("nil") is not equal to ("Optional(5)") -`

Am I doing something incorrectly with regard to the `Codable` protocol that is causing this failure? If not, then what is causing my second test to fail with this seemingly-simple cast?

[image: Screenshot of failing unit test in Xcode]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're seeing has to do with a combination of how your `init(with: Decoder)` is written, and how `DataDecoder` type decodes its type argument. Since the test is failing with `nil != Optional(5)`, then either `uvIndex` or `currentWeatherReport` is `nil` in `currentWeatherReport?.uvIndex`.

Let's see how `uvIndex` might be `nil`. Since it's an `Int?`, it gets a default value of `nil` if not otherwise initialized, so that's a good place to start looking. How might it get assigned its default value?

```
internal init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    if let uvIndexInteger = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .uvIndex) {
        // Clearly assigned to here
        uvIndex = uvIndexInteger
    } else if let uvIndexString = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .uvIndex) {
        // Clearly assigned to here
        uvIndex = Int(uvIndexString)
    }

    // Hmm, what happens if neither condition is true?
}
```

Hmm. So, if decoding as both an `Int` and a `String` fail (because the value isn't present), you'll get `nil`. But clearly, this isn't always the case, since the first test passes (and a value is indeed there).

So, on to the next failure mode: if an `Int` is clearly being decoded, why is the `String` not decoding properly? Well, when `uvIndex` is a `String`, the following decode call is still made:

```
try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .uvIndex)
```

That call only returns `nil` if a value isn't present (i.e. there's no value for the given key, or the value is explicitly `null`); if a value *is* present but is not an `Int`, the call will `throw`.

Since the error being thrown isn't caught and explicitly handled, it propagates up immediately, never calling `try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .uvIndex)`. Instead, the error bubbles up to where `CurrentWeatherReport` is decoded:

```
internal final class func decode(_ data: Data) -> T? {
    return try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
}
```

Since this code `try?`s, the error gets swallowed up, returning `nil`. That `nil` makes its way to the original `currentWeatherReport?.uvIndex` call, which ends up being `nil` not because `uvIndex` was missing, but because the whole report failed to decode.

Likely, the `init(with: Decoder)` implementation that fits your needs is more along the lines of the following:

```
internal init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    // try? container.decode(...) returns nil if the value was the wrong type or was missing.
    // You can also opt to try container.decode(...) and catch the error.
    if let uvIndexInteger = try? container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .uvIndex) {
        uvIndex = uvIndexInteger
    } else if let uvIndexString = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .uvIndex) {
        uvIndex = Int(uvIndexString)
    } else {
        // Not strictly necessary, but might be clearer.
        uvIndex = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Your implementation worked as expected, and your explanation was well-understood.

Comment: @NickKohrn Great, happy to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

You could try [SafeDecoder](https://github.com/Beyova/SafeDecoder)

```swift
import SafeDecoder

internal struct CurrentWeatherReport: Codable {

  internal var uvIndex: Int?

}
```

Then just decode as usual.