# How to write the codable in generic format

Tags: swift, generics, codable

I have understand how to make the codable wrapper class for services response structure.
But some times in server side the attribute value varies It may Int Or String.

Example

```
struct ResponseDataModel : Codable{
    let data : DataClass?
    enum  CodingKey: String, CodingKey{
        case data = "data"

    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throw {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        data = try values.decodeIfPresent(DataClass.self, forKey:.data)
    }
}

struct DataClass : Codable{
    let id : Int
    let name : String?
    let age : Int?

    enum  CodingKey: String, CodingKey{
        case id = "id"
        case name = "name"
        case age = "age"

    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throw {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey:.it)
        name = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey:.name)
        age = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey:.age)
    }
}
```

I would like to use generic way if id int string no matter what its it should bind to my controller with id value data.

```
let id : <T>
```

How to write the codable in generic formate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What Is Preventing My Conversion From String to Int When Decoding Using Swift 4’s Codable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48513704/what-is-preventing-my-conversion-from-string-to-int-when-decoding-using-swift-4) Using this logic you don't need to know before hand if it is an Int or String which you need to do with a generic solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using the following model:

```
struct ResponseDataModel<T: Codable>: Codable{
    let data : DataClass<T>?
    enum  CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case data = "data"

    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        data = try values.decodeIfPresent(DataClass<T>.self, forKey:.data)
    }
}

struct DataClass<T: Codable>: Codable {
    let id: T?
    let name: String?
    let age: Int?

    enum  CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case id = "id"
        case name = "name"
        case age = "age"

    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try values.decodeIfPresent(T.self, forKey:.id)
        name = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey:.name)
        age = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey:.age)
    }
}
```

However, you should always known the type of the `id` property when you call `decode(_:from:)` function of `JSONDecoder` like this:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()

do {
    let decoded = try decoder.decode(ResponseDataModel<Int>.self, from: data)
    print(decoded)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Or you can use the following model to always map the `id` as `Int`, even if your server sends it as `String`:

```
struct ResponseDataModel: Codable{
    let data : DataClass?
    enum  CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case data = "data"

    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        data = try values.decodeIfPresent(DataClass.self, forKey:.data)
    }
}

struct DataClass: Codable {
    let id: Int?
    let name: String?
    let age: Int?

    enum  CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case id = "id"
        case name = "name"
        case age = "age"

    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        do {
            id = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey:.id)
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            if let idString = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey:.id) {
                id = Int(idString)
            } else {
                id = nil
            }
        }
        name = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey:.name)
        age = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey:.age)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [@Joakim Danielson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9223839/joakim-danielson) example provided, you can reach desired result by attempting to decode value for each type.

```swift
struct Response: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let name: String?
    let age: Int?
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data
    }
    
    private enum NestedCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case age
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let nestedContainer = try container.nestedContainer(
            keyedBy: NestedCodingKeys.self,
            forKey: .data
        )
        
        if let id = try? nestedContainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id) {
            self.id = String(id)
        } else {
            id = try nestedContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        }
        
        name = try nestedContainer.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
        age = try nestedContainer.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .age)
    }
}
```

As [@gcharita](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6791677/gcharita) [illustrated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63774436/7890303) you can also catch `DecodingError`, but do-catch statement for `decode(_:forKey:)` would act only as an early exit, since it throws one of the following errors - `typeMismatch`, `keyNotFound` or `valueNotFound` for that particular key-value pair.

Comment: Why not vote to close this a a duplicate instead?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, here are some key points to take case when using `Codable` for parsing.

1. There is no need to every time implement `enum CodingKeys` if the property names and keys have exactly same name.
2. Also, no need to implement `init(from:)` if there no specific parsing requirements. `Codable` will handle all the parsing automatically if the models are written correctly as per the format.

So, with the above 2 improvements your `ResponseDataModel` looks like,

```
struct ResponseDataModel : Codable{
    let data: DataClass?
}
```

Now, for `DataClass` you simply need to add an `if-else` condition to handle the `Int` and `String` cases. Implementing *generics* is not needed here.

Use `String` or `Int` as the type for `id`. And add the conditions accordingly. In the below code, I'm using `id` as `String`.

```
struct DataClass : Codable {
    let id : String //here....
    let name : String?
    let age : Int?
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
        age = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .age)

        if let id = try? values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id) {
            self.id = String(id)
        } else {
            self.id = try values.decode(String.self, forKey:.id)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not have the expected result. If the `id` is `String`, `decodeIfPresent(_:forKey:)` function will throw a `DecodingError.typeMismatch` error and whatever is inside `else` statement will never be executed.

Comment: Also, this approach (after update) will ignore malformed JSON when it should throw an error.

Comment: @gcharita No it won't. That will be handled by the catch statement while parsing the `data`.

Comment: @gcharita do-catch block for `decode(_:forKey:)` would act only as early exit, since it throws one of the following - `typeMismatch`, `keyNotFound` or `valueNotFound` for that particular key-value pair

Comment: @PGDev you are right, the error will be thrown from the second `try`. (because `try?` will return `nil` when JSON is malformed)

Comment: Why not vote to close this a a duplicate instead?